# Supporting multiple versions of NuGet package in one library / NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

#### What I want

I want my library to work with a range of versions of a NuGet package with breaking changes in API between the changes. I haven't investigated it further, but this path looks promising:

- Reference all versions of the library with different APIs by specifying [extern namespace aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias).
- Create proxies for the needed classes, with flags/exceptions/whatever to tell what's actually supported.
- Choose the correct proxy at runtime depending on what version is actually loaded into the application.
- Code which depends on non-existent API won't be called, so everything should work fine.

While this may seem complicated, it has many benefits over a more straightforward approach of supporting every version in a separate assembly:

- Version of my library won't become a mess like 1.2.3-for-2.3.4-to-2.6.8. I don't even know how versioning is supposed to work in this case.
- NuGet users won't have to choose between several packages, one package fits all.
- Upgrading versions would be straightforward, won't require removing and adding my package.

#### Problem

However, it's unclear whether it's possible at all. Even before getting to proxies and detecting current version, I'm stuck with the basics.

I can't even add multiple `PackageReference` nodes to my .csproj, only one reference actually works. There's a [workaround for adding extern aliases](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989) which aren't supported by NuGet directly, but I can't get to that point because I can't get two references. And if I somehow get two, I won't be able to tell them apart.

#### Questions

1. Can support for multiple versions be implemented this way, using extern namespace aliases and proxies?
2. If yes, how to add references to multiple versions of a NuGet package and use them in code?
3. If not, what is the correct approach then?

#### Background

I'm working on CsConsoleFormat library for formatting Console output. I want to support all relevant versions of popular command-line packages directly, so that pretty command line help and stuff like this could be added with almost no coding, no matter what command line parsing library is used.

I guess declaring "I support only the latest version" is somewhat acceptable in my case, but I'd rather have wider support even if it's more complicated. Ideally, **I want a NuGet package which declares dependency on the lowest supported version, but supports everything up to the latest version**.

#### Progress so far

I kinda got it to work, but with many issues. See [issue on GitHub NuGet Home](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6693) for more details.

Comment: Do you require your package to be single-dll? I mean nuget package might include multiple dlls, and when you install it they all will be referenced by target project.

Comment: @Evk It [isn't supported by SDK-based projects](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891) yet either. And if I go that route, my sources would become more messy because I'll have to precisely put all version-specific code to separate assemblies, instead of relying on non-inlined methods like in case of extern aliases. The output of the consumer project woul be messy too, with potentially many libraries which aren't required for it to run. Overall, I think this approach would be strictly worse than extern aliases, even if it was officially supported.

Comment: There are workarounds for that which actually work (tried myself), but the rest is true - consumer will reference all those dlls when installing your package.

Comment: You can do what you want by referencing dlls directly (via `Reference` and not package reference). Include all versions except min as `Reference` with `SpecificVersion` and `Aliases`, then include min version as `PackageReference`. In result you will have aliases as you like to all versions (min version will be available without alias from global:: namespace). Packed nuget will just have dependency on >= min version as you need, additional dlls (other versions) will not be included in package. I just tried and it works like this (though there is "conflict between versions" warning of course).

Answer (score 15):

If you insist on extern aliases - you can add multiple version references directly, as dll file, not as nuget package.

Suppose I want to take a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json package version 10.0.3+.
However if user has version 11 installed - I want to use generic `JsonConverter<T>` class available only in this version (11). Then my csproj might look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.0.4</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Nuget reference -->
    <!-- Only this one will be included as dependency to the packed nuget -->
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Direct reference to the specific version -->
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed">
      <!-- Path to v11 dll -->
      <HintPath>Newtonsoft.Json.v11.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>js11</Aliases>
      <SpecificVersion>true</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>    
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I have proxy interface:

```
public interface ISerializer {
    string Serialize<T>(T obj);
}
```

And two implementations, v10 (uses global, non-aliased namespace):

```
using System;
using global::Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NugetRefMain {
    internal class Js10Serializer : ISerializer
    {
        public string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(JsonConvert));
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And v11

```
extern alias js11;
using System;
using js11::Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NugetRefMain {
    internal class Js11Serializer : ISerializer {
        public string Serialize<T>(T obj) {
            // using JsonConverter<T>, only available in v11
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(JsonConverter<T>));
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally factory which creates serializer depending on current available json.net version:

```
public static class Serializers {
    public static ISerializer Create() {
        var version = typeof(JsonConvert).Assembly.GetName().Version;
        if (version.Major == 10)
            return new Js10Serializer();
        return new Js11Serializer();
    }
}
```

Now if I pack this as nuget - it will have single dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json` version `10.0.3` and that's all. However, if user installs `Newtonsoft.Json` of version 11 - it will use capabilities available in this version.

Drawbacks:

- Visual Studio \ Resharper intellisense doesn't like this approach sometimes and shows intellisense errors when in reality everything compiles just fine.
- You might have "version conflict" warnings on compilation.

Answer (score 3):

NuGet only resolves single package versions.

If you declare a dependency on the minimum supported version, any referencing project can upgrade the dependency to a newer version.

As long as the authors of the dependent package don't introduce breaking changes, it should work find.

Even if you use reflection to look at the actual assembly versions used, you will find that many package authors don't change the assembly version between releases. This is to avoid the need for binding redirects in classic .NET Framework projects as all versions are the same and NuGet will select the right DLL based on the resolved package version of the consuming project. Again, this is good for as long as there are no breaking changes.

A pattern you could use to support different packages is to provide many "platform" packages that the consumer can choose from. The platform-specific package would then reference a common package with shareable logic.

The "platform" would then be e.g. "MyLogic.XUnit" or "MyLogic.NUnit" (assuming test helpers as example) referencing "MyLogic.Common"

Comment: The problem is that I want "MyLogic.NUnit" from your example to support a wide range of NUnit versions, so instead of a single "MyLogic.NUnit" package, packages like "MyLogic.NUnit-1", "MyLogic.NUnit-2", "MyLogic.NUnit-2.2" become necessary, which makes both maintaining the packages and using them painful.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a complete answer but I noticed on your [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6693) that you are referencing both .NET Standard and .NET Framework libraries in your project. This is known to NOT work correctly.

Quoting .NET Standard team's [announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481),

> .. Another symptom is warnings at build time regarding assembly versions ..

which may be what you are running into.

Comment: Could be a comment instead of an answer