# .NET Core pull-down NuGet packages to User cache

Tags: caching, .net-core, reference, package, nuget

I have a `.NET Core 2.2.0` app that references various `NuGet` packages.

`.NET Core` relies on `PackageReference` style packages defined in `.csproj` project files.  It does not rely on `packages.config`

Nevertheless I expected `Restore NuGet Packages` ( or `Build` ) to pull-down all referenced packages and their dependency packages into the project `packages` folder ( peer level to `.csproj` or `.sln` file ).

I expected this because my understanding is that `.NET Core` follows many of the conventions of open-source package managers such as `npm` that operate on the principle of self-sufficient app domains.

However the vast majority of the packages are pulled-down to this folder :

`C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\`

( A couple packages **are** pulled into the project `packages` folder - and I don't see what about these packages is different. )

Apparently `Visual Studio` and/or `NuGet` prefers to avoid duplication of effort and cache almost all packages centrally.

Why is this ? And can it be configured differently ?

Comment: What is the "principle of self-sufficient app domains"? All packages are cached in a central location to reduce duplication (save disk space, reduce download time). After all, it's just a cache. Why would you want to change it?

Comment: Deploy-sets and containers.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand at all. Is that the meaning of "principle of self-sufficient app domains"? What is a "deploy-set"? The nuget package cache is a development-time thing. After you publish your application, the nuget cache is not used by the application.

Comment: If all referenced packages are located in a packages folder in the app domain then it's clear which versions are being used.

Answer (score 1):

First, the "open source package manager" behaviour you describe is not really an "open source package manager" behaviour. It's an implementation of *some* package managers. Java's Maven (`mvn`), for example, does the same thing as .NET Core and you can't claim maven is closed source.

Second, some package managers, such as `npm` copy over all dependencies into a package directory (eg, `node_modules`) because they use sources, not binaries, and because they grab transitive sources and multiple dependencies same names but different versions. NuGet doesn't do that. It uses binaries only and doesn't support multiple versions. NuGet only resolves exactly one version for each dependency in your project. [See this stackoverflow post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307481/supporting-multiple-versions-of-nuget-package-in-one-library-nuget-package). The exact version resolved and used is written out to the `.deps.json` file in your build directory.

Third, .NET Core's Self-Contained Deployments - which are meant to be executible/distributable without any other additional dependencies - don't make use of the package cache. When you publish your application (`dotnet publish` on the command line), all the dependencies are copied to the publish directory. The version is that in the `deps.json` file, like I said above.

So the main nuget package cache - which is shared on your system with other projects - is just a simple cache of binaries for .NET Core. There's no reason it has to be unique to your project to copied over to your project directory.

Comment: In my `.csproj` I have a `PackageReference` to `Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2`. `dotnet publish` run local writes `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` `v12.0.2` to `publish` folder. But on `TeamCity` `dotnet publish` copies `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` `v9.0.2` to publish folder. This happens even if I include `packages.lock.json`. Referenced Microsoft packages do have indirect dependencies on both `v9.0.2` and `v12.0.2` ( and many other versions as well ) but I don't see any restrictions on maximum version numbers so I would think `v12.0.2` would be chosen. `v9.0.2` is not compatible with one lib and so runtime error.