# What to do when two packages depend on different versions of another package?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

We have a .Net 4.8 project with a dependency on a legacy .dll which is not on NuGet. Nobody at the company is left who knows where this .dll came from but it wasn't created here, nor do we have the source code for it. We are not able to get rid of this .dll without rewriting much of the project.

#### Problem

This .dll has a hard dependency on Common.Logging 1.2.0.

We also use the NuGet package Quartz in the same project which has a dependency on Common.Logging >= 2.1.2.

I don't know how to use a binding redirect to solve this as the legacy .dll can't use a newer version of Common.Logging and Quartz can't use an older version.

Currently this isn't causing any major problems other than a compiler warning about a version mismatch, but I'd like to get rid of the warning if at all possible.

#### Question

Is there a way to have two versions of Common.Logging in our project and configure the legacy.dll to use version 1.2.0 and have Quartz use the newer version?

If not, is there a standard way to resolve this version mismatch?

#### Summary:

Package A depends on Package C (version = 1)
Package B depends on Package C (version >= 2)

Comment: You can't solve this with binding redirects. `Common.Logging` was essentially abandoned because that functionality is now available through .NET's ILogger. `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is a .NET Standard 2.0 package which means you can use it in .NET Framework 4.8 as well.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443096/9796331) help at all?

Comment: If you have such an old library you should probably start looking at ways to decompile it using tools like JustDecompile. Common.Logging is essentially abandoned.  1.2 is 11 years old and the last version came out in 2017, 5 years ago. All logging libraries support `ILogger`. Whatever library you use for actual logging will work with it, unless it's also discontinued

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. @madmonk46 the solution in your link looks like it might work, but seems like too much of a workaround instead of a permanent solution.

Comment: @Panagiotis Thanks for pointing me in the direction of decompiling. I'd never really done it before but this looks like the direction we need to go with this .dll long-term.